# iOS Swift4 how to reconcile T.Type and type(of:) to pass dynamic class type as function parameter?

Tags: ios, generics, swift4, typechecking, type-safety

I'm trying implement generic storage of configuration parameters by using class type string as a dictionary key. The idea is that the retrieve function will return an object of proper type. Each type is unique in the storage.  However, when I call the function, I'm getting a Swift compiler error and am not sure how interpret it:

```
Compiler Error: 
Cannot invoke 'retrieve' with an argument list of type '(type: Any.Type)
```

I checked the documentation, and it seems like the `type(of:)` method is supposed to return runtime class, while the compiler makes it look like it's complaining because it thinks I'm passing a type of Any

**How do I pass Swift class name as a function parameter without using an instance of that class?**

```
func retrieve<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {

    let valueKey = String(describing: type)
    print("retrieving: \(valueKey)")
    return dictionary[valueKey] as? T
}
func update(with value: Any) {
    let valueKey = String(describing: type(of: value))
    print("Updating: \(valueKey)")
    dictionary[valueKey] = value
}

let testCases: [Any] = [1, 2.0, "text"]

for testCase in testCases {
    subject.update(with: testCase)
    //Compiler Error: Cannot invoke 'retrieve' with an argument list of type '(type: Any.Type)
    let t = type(of: testCase)
    let retrieved = subject.retrieve(type: t)
    //check for equality
}
//this works
expect(subject.retrieve(type: Int.self)).to(equal(1))
expect(subject.retrieve(type: Double.self)).to(equal(2.0))
expect(subject.retrieve(type: String.self)).to(equal("text"))
```

I've done more testing, and see that it appears my array does not honor the [type(of: ) documentation,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) and this function returns the same object as "Any":

```
func retrieve<T>(sample: T) -> T? {

    let valueKey = String(describing: type(of: sample))
    print("retrieving: \(valueKey)") //always retrieves same object "Any"
    return dictionary[valueKey] as? T
}
```

**Updated: Thank you for responses, to clarify** - test cases were intended to begin with simple types, then progress to more complex classes. The actual implementation would store completely unique instances of custom types, not Strings or Ints.

```
let testCases: [Any] = [ConnectionConfig(...),
                                    AccountID("testID"),
                                    AccountName("testName")]
```

The tests recognize the generic nature of the retrieve function and assign appropriate types, as evidenced by code completion:

```
    expect(subject.retrieve(type: ConnectionConfig.self)?.ip).to(equal("defaultIP"))
    expect(subject.retrieve(type: AccountID.self)?.value).to(equal("testId"))
```

The intended end use within RxSwift context: provide the generic storage to a class and allow it to pull the appropriate values for configuration parameters. If no value exists, an error is thrown and is handled by a separate error handler:

```
class RxConfigConsumer: ConfigConsumer {
    var connection: ConnectionConfig?
    var accountID: AccountID?

    init(with provider: ConfigProvider) {
        connection = provider.retrieve(type: ConnectionConfig.self)
        accountID = provider.retrieve(type: AccountID.self)
        //etc
    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to introduce a kind of type dynamism or use of metatypes as objects to which Swift is not congenial. Sounds like an x-y problem. What's the _real_ goal here?

Comment: What types do you believe `1` and `2.0` are in the above code? You seem to be expecting that `1` has a deep connection to `Int`, but that's not true. The token `1` is an IntegerLiteral and can be used to instantiate a variety of types (anything that conforms to `ExpressiblebyIntegerLiteral`). The only meaningful type to assign it in your above code is `Any` (as it does). So what type do you think `t` is going to be (and more specifically, what type do you believe it would be assigned at *compile-time*)?

Comment: To explore this code further, please explicitly type-annotate `t` and `retrieved` in the above code. If you cannot unambiguously put `: Something` after the definition, then the compiler can't either. Type inference just means "when the type is unambiguous you don't have to type it." It doesn't mean you don't have to know it. How would you implement the "check for equality" line?

Comment: @RobNapier I see your point, I expected that the compiler would figure out the runtime type of of each case, but if it doesn't, this simply means that I cannot have a simple test case like I expected. I need to explicitly try to retrieve items by class name

Answer (score 2):

The combination of a generic with a metatype (`.Type`) is very weird and is probably what's tripping you up. If you get rid of the generic things work as you would expect:

```
func retrieve(_ T:Any.Type) {
    print(type(of:T))
}
let testCases: [Any] = [1, 2.0, "text"]
for testCase in testCases {
    retrieve(type(of:testCase))
}
// Int.Type, Double.Type, String.Type
```

If you really want the generic, then get rid of the `.Type` and write it like this:

```
func retrieve<T>(_ t:T) {
    print(type(of:t))
}
let testCases: [Any] = [1, 2.0, "text"]
for testCase in testCases {
    retrieve(type(of:testCase))
}
// Int.Type, Double.Type, String.Type
```

Even then, however, it's unclear to me what the point is of passing the metatype.

Comment: This does not work, the retrieved type becomes  Double.Type? , not Double? as I want. The metatype is used as a storage and retrieval key. It also casts the return to the correct type, allowing for code like accountID = subject.retrieve(type: AccountID.self)

Comment: Well, as I said, the goal was unclear to me. It appeared to me that I was getting the same answer as your code that you said "worked", but whatever. I don't endorse what you're trying to do, I just wanted to show how to get the code to compile.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is what you're trying to do is impossible, because there is no way to type-annotate the following line of code:

```
let retrieved = subject.retrieve(type: t)
```

What is the static type, known at compile-time, of `retrieved`? It can't change at run-time. It certainly can't change from iteration to iteration. The compiler needs to allocate space for it. How much space does it require? Does it require space on the stack or heap? There's no way to know. The best we can say is that it's `Any` and put a box around it. `1` doesn't even have a proper type anyway. It's just an integer literal. It could be a `Float` or many other things (try `let x: Float = 1` and see).

The answer is you can't build a loop like this. Your individual test cases are the right ones. Once you create an `[Any]`, it is very difficult to get "real" types back out. Avoid it. If you have a more concrete problem beyond the example you've given, we can discuss how to deal with that, but I believe outside of a unit test, this specific problem shouldn't come up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and you can run the following codes in a playground.

The first step is to solve the T.Type parameter. It's hard to put it into a function call. So to achieve your goal, we can use T but T.Type.

```
class MySubject {

 var dictionary : [String : Any] = [:]

 func retrieve<T>(type1: T) -> T? {

   let valueKey = String(describing: (type(of: type1)))
   print("retrieving: \(valueKey)")
   return dictionary[valueKey] as? T
  }
 func update(with value: Any) {
   let valueKey = String(describing: type(of: value))
    print("Updating: \(valueKey)")
    dictionary[valueKey] = value
   }

  }
 var subject : MySubject = MySubject()
 let testCases: [Any] = [1, 2.0, "text"]

for testCase in testCases {
    subject.update(with: testCase)
   //Compiler Error: Cannot invoke 'retrieve' with an argument list of type     '(type: Any.Type)

    let retrieved = subject.retrieve(type1: testCase)
    //check for equality
}
```

The compilation is correct. But as you said, the return value is nil as a result of a generic retrieve Function. In order to achieve your goal, we may skip the generic way, use Any directly.

```
class MySubject {

var dictionary : [String : Any] = [:]

func retrieve(type1: Any) -> Any? {
    let valueKey = String(describing: (type(of: type1)))
    print("retrieving: \(valueKey)")
    return dictionary[valueKey]
}
func update(with value: Any) {
    let valueKey = String(describing: type(of: value))
    print("Updating: \(valueKey)")
    dictionary[valueKey] = value
}
}

var subject : MySubject = MySubject()
let testCases: [Any] = [1, 2.0, "text"]

for testCase in testCases {
  subject.update(with: testCase)
//Compiler Error: Cannot invoke 'retrieve' with an argument list of type '(type: Any.Type)
  let retrieved = subject.retrieve(type1: testCase)
  //check for equality
 }
```

Currently everything is perfect as you wish. But this brings up an interesting thought about generic. Is it O.K. or right to use generic here? As we know, there is a presumption in generic, which is represented by letters T, U, V. They have one common meaning: Type. When we try to use generic, we assume every parameter should have only one unique type.  So in first case, Any is the only type and should be accepted without question in a generic call.  There is no other type will be revealed during function call.

This kind of misunderstanding roots from the use of `"let testCases: [Any] = [1, 2.0, "text"]`. Although swift allows you to write this way, they are not a normal array. They are a list which contains different type essentially. So you can ignore fancy generic here without any regrets. Just pick the Any to solve your problem.